# How to override a third-party installation directory with inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

I need to install a thirdparty software embedded in a installer named `thirdparty-installer.exe` and also install my application `Instruct.exe`. My application will be at `c:\MyAPP` folder and all my thirdparty files must be at `c:\windows\system32` (all files will be thrown there, in the system32 root). I have done the following:

```
#define OutputDirectory_MPP "c:\myAPP"

[setup]
DefaultDirName=c:\MyAPP
DisableDirPage=yes

[dirs]
Name: {#OutputDirectory_MPP}; Attribs: system

[files]
Source: "g:\application\Instruct.exe"; DestDir: {#OutputDirectory_MPP}
Source: "g:\applicationr\thirdparty-installer.exe"; DestDir: "{cf}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs promptifolder; Permissions: system-full;

[Run]
Filename: "{cf}\thirdparty-installer.exe"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated 
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

(...)

My Instruct.exe installs normally, and when it finishes, the thirdparty-installer prompts and show the user the option to change installation directory. Their default is `c:\program files\Thirdparty2020\`

How can I impose their installation to be on the `c:\windows\system32` folder and leave no option to the user? (possibly even coupled with a silent install).

Comment: Telling third-party installer, we do not know anything about, where to install the files is neither a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) nor [tag:inno-setup] question. + Installing files to `system32` is just wrong.

Comment: @martin prikryl it is an innosetup question because I need to install my software and someone's software at the same time in just one go. The third party sotware can be photoshop., autocad, winnamp, Unity etc.

Comment: There's no universal way to specify a directory for an installer. It's different for every installer. All that Inno Setup does is that it executes a program with arguments. Finding out what those arguments are is not an [tag:inno-setup] question.

Comment: Indeed, there are other Inno Setup questions that are mainly about arguments of some command-line tools. Those are indeed on the edge of being off-topic. But they are at least pretty specific, about tasks with ***specific widely*** used tools. So about something that others may find useful later. As I wrote already, *"There's no universal way to specify a directory for an [any] installer"*. You didn't tell us anything about the tool (installer) you are trying to automate. Your question is too vague.

Comment: the third-party installation software I tested, which is bundled with my application_installer is, in this example, WINRAR.

Comment: Please do not post important information in comments. Edit your question. As you have primarily a [tag:winrar] question, the *"WinRAR"* should feature prominently in your question title and tags. + Do you mean WinRAR installer, or WinRAR-made self-extracting archive? (though possibly WinRAR installer is actually WinRAR-made self-extracting archive – I do not know).

Comment: I cannot feature Winrar in a title because (and I explained that to you already) Winrar is just an example. When I meant Winrar, I meant the installer (latest version Winrar-x64-591tr.exe).

Comment: For the third time: *"There's no universal way to specify a directory for an [any] installer. It's different for every installer."*